# "nunca" placement after a verb with "no"

Tags: gramática, negación

I was reading the sentences:

> Yo nunca hago ejercicio.
>
> Los sábados no me levanto nunca pronto.

and according to what my teacher said to me, if you use "nunca" after a verb, you need to add a "no" before the verb too.

But this left me slightly confused. If "no" is used just as in English to negate the following sentence, in the sentence above:

> Los sábados no me levanto nunca pronto.

which translates to

> On Saturdays, I never get up early.

are we not actually negating the idea that *on Saturdays, I never get up early*? i.e.

> On Saturday, I never not get up early

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question! Partial argument: Unlike English, double negation is used in Spanish for emphasis, somehow intensifying the negation, not nullifying it.

Comment: @walen isn't that "no" just an affirmative "no" though i.e. "Vamos a la fiesta esta noche ¿no?" so it doesn't function in that negation way?

Answer (score 6):

Spanish has a feature called *negative concord(ance)*.  While you're probably used to making sure that things agree in gender, number, person, tense, etc., *another* thing you have to do is make sure that things agree in polarity (affirmative/negative).

Thankfully, there are only a few pairs of words that require this type of agreement.  *Siempre/nunca* is one of them.  If your sentence is negative, then you may not use *siempre*, *algo*, *algún<sub>/o/a/os/as</sub>*, *alguien*, *<sub>(o…)</sub>o*, etc.  You must use the negative version of them:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ AFFIRMATIVE    NEGATIVE  ┃
┠──────────────────────────┨
┃   sí            no       ┃
┃   siempre       nunca    ┃
┃   algo          nada     ┃
┃   algún…        ningún…  ┃
┃   alguien       nadie    ┃
┃   también       tampoco  ┃
┃  (o …) o       (ni …) ni ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

English does not have negative concordance.  A single negative element is sufficient to negate the action, thus *I don't see anyone* and *I see no one* are equivalent.  In Spanish, the negative concord means that you must have both/all elements negated, so you get *No veo a nadie*.

If any negative element comes before the verb then the verb is implicitly made negative, and doesn't require additional negating.

Comment: "If your sentence is negative, then you may not use siempre, algo, algún/o/a/os/as, alguien, (o…)o, etc." But note that "Los sábados no me levanto siempre pronto" is valid (I don't always get up early on Saturdays). I don't know my grammar that well, but it seems to me that, in the table above, the pair "siempre - nunca" could be replaced with "a veces - nunca", which would make it more coherent with the other pairs ("algo - nada" instead of "todo - nada", etc.)

Answer (score 0):

*This is a supplement to the complete, technical answer by @guifa.*

First, let me replace *pronto* with *temprano*.  I checked the dictionary and found that *pronto* can be used to mean "early," but in the regional variant of Spanish that I know, it doesn't mean that at all -- it means "soon."  Also, I'll adjust the word order to a more comfortable one.  It feels awkward to me to have two adverbs right next to each other -- so I'll move one to a different part of the sentence.  Finally, I'll use a singular *sábado* because that's the idiomatic way to talk about Saturdays in general in Spanish.  The result:

> El sábado no me levanto temprano nunca.

This would be equivalent to

> Saturdays I don't get up early, ever.

You could think of **no ... nunca** as

> ... never *ever*.

Your teacher is right.  If the *nunca* appears at the tail end of the sentence, it needs to have the basic negation word, *no*, near the beginning, because the *nunca* at the tail end is only there for emphasis -- rather like the "ever" in "never *ever*."

Now I'll make up a dialogue where the extra emphasis would make sense.

> A: Ay, Mamá, ¿por qué sacaste cita con la doctora para el sábado a las 8? `Jeez, Mama, why did you make the doctor's appointment for Saturday at 8 am?`
>
> B: Así podremos ir al súpermercado a buena hora.  Si no, habrá muchísima gente en el súper y se acaban las cosas, como el pan.  `That way we'll be able to get to the grocery store at a good time.  Otherwise, it will be really crowded and they'll be out of things, like bread.`
>
> A: Pero ya sabes, el sábado no me levanto temprano nunca.  El sábado es mi único día de descanso.  `But you know that I never get up early on Saturday, *ever*.  Saturday is my one day off work.`